# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, pecl

I want to use mongodb  in laravel project. so I tried to install mongodb driver for php by running this command `pecl install mongodb` on cmd but I got this answer

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"
> install failed

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a windows machine, go to the official pecl website:
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb
then click on the DLL link for your version of choice.

On next page scroll down and download the one matching your PHP version.

Then you should extract the zip file and copy the `php_mongodb.dll` to your `php/ext` dir. Then open your `php.ini` and add the following line:

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tested this solution by installing thread safe version and then I get Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found error. After searching more around the problem I found that should use non thread safe version for laravel and then problem fixed. –

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because for some minutes, the PECL repositories were not accessible. The error was happening both on CI an my local (both on Linux) and after some minutes, it got fixed without any action from my side.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same problem. You can just write the following line in your command line(This will work on Mac):

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Comment: Thanks but it may work on ubuntu. On windows another solution needed.